# Programación reactiva castear un Mono<T> a T

Tags: java, programación-reactiva

Como puedo realizar el casteo de una clase `Mono<T>` a una clase `T`.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que estás intentando hacer es extraer la intancia ***T*** de ***Mono***.

Podés esperar a que ***Mono*** termine exitosamente el procesado en algún momento de tiempo y bloqueas la ejecución hasta que lo haga, utilizando el método `.bloc()`

```java
Mono<String> blockingHelloWorld() {
    return Mono.just("Hello world!");
}

String result = blockingHelloWorld().block();
assertEquals("Hello world!", result);
```